# Apache Airflow DAG doesn't call on_success_callback and on_failure_callback

Tags: python, callback, airflow

I want to customize my DAGs to send the email when it's failed or succeeded. I'm trying to use on_success_callback and on_failure_callback in DAG constructor, but it doesn't work for DAG. In the same time it works for DummyOperator that I put inside my DAG.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

from utils import get_report_operator, DagStatus


TEST_DAG_NAME='test_dag'
TEST_DAG_REPORT_SUBSCRIBERS = ['MY_EMAIL']

def send_success_report(context):
    subject = 'Airflow report: {0} run success'.format(TEST_DAG_NAME)
    email_operator = get_report_operator(subject, TEST_DAG_REPORT_SUBSCRIBERS, TEST_DAG_NAME, DagStatus.SUCCESS)
    email_operator.execute(context)

def send_failed_report(context):
    subject = 'Airflow report: {0} run failed'.format(TEST_DAG_NAME)
    email_operator = get_report_operator(subject, TEST_DAG_REPORT_SUBSCRIBERS, TEST_DAG_NAME, DagStatus.FAILED)
    email_operator.execute(context)


dag = DAG(dag_id=TEST_DAG_NAME,
          schedule_interval=None,
          start_date=datetime(2019,6,6),
          on_success_callback=send_success_report,
          on_failure_callback=send_failed_report)

DummyOperator(task_id='task',
              on_success_callback=send_success_report,
              on_failure_callback=send_failed_report,
              dag = dag)
```

I've also implemented some add-in over the Airflow EmailOperator for send report. I don't thing that error in this part, but still.

```
class DagStatus(Enum):
    SUCCESS = 0
    FAILED = 1


def get_report_operator(sbjct, to_lst, dag_id, dag_status):
    status = 'SUCCESS' if dag_status == DagStatus.SUCCESS else 'FAILED'
    status_color = '#87C540' if dag_status == DagStatus.SUCCESS else '#FF1717'
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'airflow_report.html'), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as report_file:
        report_mask = report_file.read()
    report_text = report_mask.format(dag_id, status, status_color)
    tmp_dag = DAG(dag_id='tmp_dag', start_date=datetime(year=2019, month=9, day=12), schedule_interval=None)
    return EmailOperator(task_id='send_email',
                    to=to_lst,
                    subject=sbjct,
                    html_content=report_text.encode('utf-8'),
                    dag = tmp_dag)
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Instead put `on_failure_callback` as argument in `default_args` dictionary and pass it to DAG. 
All arguments in `defaut_args` passed to a DAG will be applied to all of DAG's operators. Its the only way, as of now, to apply a common parameter to all the operators in the DAG.

```
dag = DAG(dag_id=TEST_DAG_NAME,      
          schedule_interval=None,
          start_date=datetime(2019,6,6),
          default_args={
              'on_success_callback': send_success_report,
              'on_failure_callback': send_failed_report
          })
```

Comment: If there's a plan to upgrade to Airflow 2.0, it's important to avoid using parameters in default_args that do not apply to all Operators; otherwise, version 2.0+ will cause an error to be thrown. Unless you change a specific setting in the `airflow.cfg` file.

Comment: Somewhy adding on_failure_callback to default args causes Airflow 2.6.2 to stop reading the dag( Commenting it out takes everything on track

Comment: @cdabel I am using 2.2.2 and having issue where most of the time the function mentioned against the default args "on_success_callback" is triggered but sometime it completes the task as succeeded but fails the downstream. Can you guide me which airflow.cfg setting needs to be changed in my case.

Comment: @HammadAhmed, could you please create a new question and tag me or message it to me to look at? I'd like more information about the problem to be able to help you better. Regarding my comment above, I believe the issue I mentioned has been fixed, so that that doesn't happen anymore. Here is a link to look at:  https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/29913